# Characters as marks in pgfplots ycomb

Tags: pgfplots

I need to use characters as marks in pgfplots ycomb in 3D plot. [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247768/using-a-character-as-mark-in-pgfplots) was very helpful, but the ycomb stem interferes with the letter.

Any hints, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I 
If you use the second method described there, just add `anchor=south` to the style of the text mark.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[ycomb,
             samples=5,
             mark=text,
             text mark=A,
             text mark as node,
             text mark style={anchor=south}
             ] {rnd};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```